# Umbraco property custom editor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, content-management-system, umbraco

I'm trying to create a property editor in Umbraco that will select certain type of content from a dropdown list. I have managed to get a basic plugin running from examples online, but am struggling to work out how to populate any content based on the CMS content. Any advice on which resources to do this...

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new Data Type.
Go to developers tab > Data types and create a new one.

In the field "Property editor", select "Ultimate Picker".

[image: new data type example]

(In this case, I was using Umbraco6.)

After create the Data Type, it'll be available when you create a new property in some Document Type

[image]